# c++ use dynamic_cast when casting type is only known as string

Tags: c++, types, casting, dynamic-cast

I have several classes which derive from another class.

```
class t1 : fu
class t2 : fu
....
```

I have to dynamically create objects of `fu` first and cast it to a derived class later on.

This would be a working static way:

```
t1 vart1_1 = dynamic_cast<t1 *>(fu1);
t1 vart1_2 = dynamic_cast<t1 *>(fu2);
t2 vart2_1 = dynamic_cast<t2 *>(fu3);
```

Problem is, I don't know before run time which and how many fu-objects I have.

What I get is a list

```
list[]={{string type, string fuName},{string type, string fuName}, ...}
```

I would like to iterate through the list, create the fu objects with the fuName and if possible make something like this:

```
type fuName = dynamic_cast<type *>(fu);
```

Another problem is that I cannot change fu and its derived classes...

I hope you understand what I want.

Comment: Perhaps someone else can confirm, but the main problem I see with that is that variable names have to be known during compilation, so trying to create those names at run time from a `string` wouldn't work.

Comment: That's a bit confused, but it sounds like you might want a *factory*... the basic idea is that some input (like the type name) is used to switch between a number of `new DerivedX` / `new DerivedY` / ... cases. The function returns a base class pointer to facilitate storage of a mix of runtime types in a container. The base class needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: One last nit-pick, `type fuName = dynamic_cast<type *>(fu);` should probably be either `type* fuName = dynamic_cast<type *>(fu);`  or `type fuName = *dynamic_cat<type*>(fu);`

Comment: This seems like a case where it would be helpful to know what you are trying to accomplish in non abstract terms, since the type of reflection you are describing isn't really possible at the moment. Who is creating these fu objects? do you have control over that code? Who is consuming these fu objects? Do you have control over that code? Your problem doesn't exist in a vacuum.

Comment: Even if this could be done, how would you use it? You cannot call derived class's methods on `fuName` if you don't know the type at compiletime.

Comment: I see how this could be useful: A base class has `string getName()` and its subclasses override this function to return their unique name. This way, code can use the superclass abstraction until the point at which the real type is needed. At that point, the super type could be downcast to its real type for processing (using the name string), while maintaining type safety. A domain message processor/dispatcher comes to mind when using value objects to represent messages.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have reflection in C++, hence you can't easily achieve what you are trying to do. 
Every attempt that I have seen to hack reflection inside of the language, has proven to be well.. just a really bad hack.

Another solution would be to try to cast it to all the derived classes, dynamic_cast will return a nullptr if the cast won't be successful.

This denotes a design problem however, you *shouldn't* need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of class names and alternative method to do the cast, then you need to check the typeid of pointer then compare the string to your list to get which method to call, for more info about typeid read this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: I would do it by hand with a static method returning the name of the function. typeid is not portable.

Comment: @dau_sama this is also  a solution, in case typeid works for his environment it is fine.